# Changing iTunes shared secret - impact on auto renewable subscriptions

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

We are selling in app purchases (auto renewable subs) on our iOS apps and it seems that some users are not able to access some of the latest content, which is part of the subscription. 
It seems that the shared secret stored in our db was not set up properly in the first place and not matching the one from the iTC account. So we corrected it, but a couple of users purchased subscriptions in the meantime. It seems that these users cannot get entitled to content since we did this change. 
Would anyone know the exact implication that this shared secret change could have caused, and if it is indeed possible that the subscriptions are not recognized anymore because of this?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: This does not have anything to do with programming per se or am I wrong?

Comment: No, but it does have something to do with the underlying purchasing logic of the iOS apps that we develop. Apologies if this was posted in the wrong section.

Comment: I feel this is off-topic for Stack Overflow. This site concerns programming problems or stuff directly connected with them.